# posix placement of stdin redirection (<in cmd vs cmd <in)

Tags: shell, io-redirection, posix

I always write stdin redirection after the command, because for me it's more natural to have first the command and then the redirections (if any):

```
some-command < input-file > output-file
```

For years, I've seen people writing the stdin redirection before the command, to have some flow direction:

```
< input-file some-command > output-file (or without spaces after < and > )
```

Is this ordering accepted by POSIX or just accepted by many shells (in my fedora 21 it is accepted by `bash`, `dash`, `tcsh`, `ksh` and `zsh`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That behavior was defined by POSIX [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07):

> If more than one redirection operator is specified with a command, the
>   order of evaluation is from beginning to end.

and [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01):

> A "simple command" is a sequence of optional variable assignments and
>   redirections, in any sequence, optionally followed by words and
>   redirections, terminated by a control operator.

This was already the case in the [Bourne shell](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/bourne/v7/), which POSIX used as a basis.

> Before a command is executed its input  and  output  may  be
>        redirected  using  a  special  notation  interpreted  by the
>        shell.  The following  may  appear  anywhere  in  a  simple-
>        command  or  may  precede  or  follow  a command and are not
>        passed on  to  the  invoked  command. (…)

Unlike the original Bourne shell, POSIX doesn't allow redirection to precede a complex command like `while … done`, `( … )`, etc.

---

A note that the order of redirection is important, because it control your command behavior and prevent you from some weird result upon failure. Example:

```
command <input >output
```

if `command` failed to read `input` (due to permission, non-existed ...) then it will be terminated without create empty file `output` if you swap the redirection position:

```
command >output <input
```

Comment: I have read this before, but it only specifies the order between redirections, but it does not specify if the redirections can appear before or after the command.

Comment: In the specification you linked, the part that seems to imply that any place is valid for a redirection to occur is the numbered list at [2.9.1 Simple commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, looks like `bash` is still fails the prefix notation, thus

```
$ < /etc/passwd while read line; do echo $line; done
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
```

while `zsh` does allow this redirection prior to the `while` loop.

Comment: That's a compound command, not  a simple command.